# How would you go about having onClickListeners on markers that have been put in using a database?

Tags: java, android

This is getting the Cursor information and breaking it down to get the name of the marker and it's Latitude and Longitude.

```
    c.moveToFirst();
   for(int i = 0; i < NumbMarkers;){
       //// Declaring Temp Variables ////
        Name = c.getString(0);
        MarkerName = Name;

       //// Getting Variables From DB ////
        LatLong = c.getString(1).split(",");
        lat = Double.parseDouble(LatLong[0]);
        lon = Double.parseDouble(LatLong[1]);
        LatLng LatLngMarker = new LatLng(lat, lon);

       //// Adding Bounds To Builder ////
       builder.include(LatLngMarker);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LatLngMarker).title(Name));

        i++;
        c.move(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            String title;
            title = arg0.getTitle();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

So I have figured this out and it was quite simple, adding this function will listen to any marker clicks and pass that marker into the onMarkerClick. In there you can do whatever you need to do when that marker is clicked.